# How can I show all this images in a carousel

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I know beginners can ask stupid questions but that is the way trough all it.
Is it possible that i can list all this images in a carousel? or image gallery. How can i list this images easiest?

What would you suggest?

I don't want to use foreignkey because I cannot (I couldn't yet understand the save process in the views) save a separate model in a view.
Thanks a lot

```
class MyFamily(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    explanatipon = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)[:30]
```

i tried to make it like @willem-van-onsem mentioned it but without success. I NEED HELP PLEASE

What did I do :

MODELS PROFILE:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

MODELS MYFAMILY:

```
class MyFamily(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    explanatipon = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    photo5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos/')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def photos(self):
        photos = [self.photo1, self.photo2, self.photo3, self.photo4, self.photo5]
        return [photo for photo in photos if photo is not None]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)[:30]
```

VİEWS :

```
def photo(request):
    myfamily = MyFamily.objects.filter(active=True)

    context = {
        'myfamily':myfamily
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/create-form.html')
```

Comment: People can only upload five photos?

Comment: no, this is only a testing model. Of course it can be more or maybe lesser. Im new in django i try to learn. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the photo's in a list:

```
class MyFamily(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def photos(self):
        photos = [self.photo1, self.photo2, self.photo3, self.photo4, self.photo5]
        return [photo for photo in photos if photo is not None]
```

If you construct a view where you pass the `MyFamily` object as `myfamily` to the template render engine, we can generate HTML for a [*Bootstrap carousel*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/):

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for photo in myfamily.photos %}
    <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ photo.url }}" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, I think the modelling might be improved with an extra model. Right now one can only upload exactly five object. Normally one defines an extra model (`MyFamilyPhoto`) with a `ForeignKey` to the `MyFamily` in this case to allow to generate an arbitrary number of `MyFamilyPhoto`s for each `MyFamily`. For an arbitrary `MyFamily` object, you will need to add a parameter to the url. In the view you can obtain the `myfamily` of the user with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def photo(request):
    myfamily = MyFamily.objects.get(active=True, author__user=request.user)
    context = {
        'myfamily': myfamily
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/create-form.html')
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: you gave me a - (minus) for a question of mine earlier but no problem you are great. Thanks
I will try it now.

Comment: @YukselBastan: I did not. The question with -1 was of someone else... I seldomly downvote (directly). But I still think the question with the data showing twice likely does not contain sufficient data. For example you use `listing_sales` in the template, but you never pass this to the template, so that will be empty. Likely the duplication is somewhere else in the template.

Comment: sorry then. I think the problem is from the view. I will paste it here. Maybe you have time to show and find the problem.

Comment: i have edited the question can you please look @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @YukselBastan: `myfamily = Post.objects.all()`, shouldn't `myfamily` be a `MyFamily` *object* (not `.all()` but a single one).

Comment: i really didnt understand what you mean, and im really at the end of my knowledge. I'm trying since days for this shit of code and i really need your help. Please.

Comment: @YukselBastan: `Post.objects.all()` will return a *collection* of *`Post`* objects, not a *single* object of *`MyFamily`** ojbects.

Comment: Do you mean Post.objects.filter(photos=photos) ?? is the rest of the edited code correct? but why couldnt i save the images?

Comment: @YukselBastan: no, why do you use `Post`, what does a `Post` has to do with a `MyFamily` model? Furthermore how does the `Profile` look like? Why is there no `OneToOneField` from `MyFamily` to `Profile`, but a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: hello, nobody here for help please?

Comment: still need help with thw views.py please

Comment: @YukselBastan: based on the `MyFamily` of the logged in user, see edit.